# Load embedded H2 database to memory

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I'm writing a portable application with embedded H2 database. So, there is 2 case:

1. *App is running from writeable storage (flash, hdd etc.)*

   It is default case. I use db file and store data into this file.

   dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
   dataSource.setURL("jdbc:h2:./" + dbfile + ";MVCC=FALSE;MV_STORE=FALSE");
2. *App is running from read-only storage (like CD, smb, tsclient etc.)*

   In this case I open file with DB, then I'm creating database in memory

   JdbcDataSource memory = new JdbcDataSource();

   memory.setURL("jdbc:h2:mem:default");

   Then I copy all data from fileDB to memoryDB using script with a lot of SELECT... INSERT...

Is there the way to load db from file to memory directly? 
May be I can copy tables more elegant way?

Comment: usage of ORM like Hibernate with H2, load objects, copy objects, persist objects

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the [SCRIPT](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#script) command:

```
SCRIPT TO '[some_location]'
```

to script the current state of your database to the filesystem.  Then use the [RUNSCRIPT](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#runscript) command:

```
RUNSCRIPT FROM '[some_location]'
```

to load your database once you've created your **jdbc:h2:mem** connection.  SCRIPT TO and RUNSCRIPT are very convenient for this type of translation and provide optional compression for large database files.